# Playing sound effect in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a button in Xcode that plays a short sound effect. I am not able to retrigger the button/sound, while it's playing. Therefore I have to wait until the sound has faded to repeat the effect. My intention is that every time I press the button, the sound effect starts to play, even if it is still fading out. Does anybody know how to achieve this? I am using XCode 11.6. My code is below. Many thanks in advance.

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "mp3")!))
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

@IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) {
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

}

Comment: do you want to pause sound effect when it's playing also play it again when it paused ?

Comment: I want it to keep it on playing when the button is pressed again, so to say that the sounds are overlaying each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just initialize the `audioPlayer` in `Play` method instead of `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "mp3")!))
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. If I copy the code and paste it, it says that "Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction".

Comment: Where did you paste this? You have to replace the methods in your code with what I've provided above.

Comment: I have replaced part of my code with your code (in the same order as you have posted it). Please excuse me, I am new to coding.

Comment: You'll receive this error only if you've posted the above code outside the `ViewController` on the top level. If you've done so, put it inside the `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to prevent play again when sound is playing and just play sound when it finished already so
you can make condition according sound is playing or not
(try it in your button action):

```
 if audioPlayer.isPlaying(){
   // your statement when sound is playing in other word nothing to do
 }else{
   // your statement when sound is not playing and you want to start play
      audioPlayer.play()
 }
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1390139-isplaying